# Add strings in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of text:

```
var text = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s");
```

I would like to add the elements in the array according to a set number and then store these in a new array. For example, if I pick 3, then the resulting strings in the new array (terms) would be: `["a b c", "d e f",  "g h i", ...]` etc

I looked at Join and I can't get this to work - it seems to only be able to add the entire array together. I'm guessing I need to use a nested loop, but I can't seem to get this to work. Here's my attempt:

```
//Outer loop
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    //Inner loop
    for (j = i; j < i + $numberWords; j++) {
        newWord = text[j];
        newPhrase = newPhrase + " " + newWord;
    }
    terms.push(newPhrase);
    i = i + $numberWords;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use various [array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) like so:

```
var input = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s");
var output = new Array();
var length = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += length) {
    output.push(input.slice(i, i + length).join(" "));
}
alert(output);
```

Variant of the above example:

```
var input = new Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s");
var output = new Array();
var length = 2;
while (input.length) {
    output.push(input.splice(0, length).join(" "))
}
alert(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var text=new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s");

var n = 3;
var a = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(text.length / 3); i++)
{
  var s = '';
  for (var j = 0; (j < n) && ((i*n)+j < text.length) ; j++)
  {
    s += text[n*i+j] + ' ';
  }
  a.push(s.trim());
}
```

Comment: You could use `.ceil()` instead of `.floor()` to grab the 19th element.

Comment: ah right, I had a floor()+1 when I was testing it and forgot to copy it. But with splice it is way cooler ;)